# What's the equivalent of Panda's value_counts() in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, count, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I am having the following python/pandas command:

```
df.groupby('Column_Name').agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().max()
```

where I am getting the value counts for ALL columns in a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

How do I do this action in PySpark?

Comment: The task I am asking very simple. I want to get the vale counts (the highest distinct count) for all columns in a group by dataframe. This is easily done in Pandas with the value_counts() method.

Comment: Here is my DF:>>> schemaTrans.show()
+----+----+------+-----+----+----+
|COL1|COL2|  COL3| COL4|COL5|  ID|
+----+----+------+-----+----+----+
| 123| 456|ABC123|  XYZ| 525|ID01|
| 123| 456|ABC123|  XYZ| 634|ID01|
| 123| 456|ABC123|  XYZ| 802|ID01|
| 456| 123|  BC01|K_L_M| 213|ID01|
| 456| 123|  BC01|K_L_M| 401|ID01|
| 456| 123|  BC01|P_Q_M| 213|ID01|
| 123| 456|XYZ012|  ABC| 117|ID02|
| 123| 456|XYZ012|  ABE| 117|ID02|
| 456| 123| QPR12|S_T_U| 204|ID02|
| 456| 123| QPR12|S_T_X| 415|ID02|
+----+----+------+-----+----+----+

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import count
exprs = {x: "count" for x in schemaTrans.columns}
schemaTrans.groupBy("ID").agg(exprs).show(5)
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 ID|count(ID)|count(COL4)|count(COL2)|count(COL3)|count(COL1)|count(COL5)|
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|ID01|        6|          6|          6|          6|          6|          6|
|ID02|        4|          4|          4|          4|          4|          4|
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------

Comment: exprs = [countDistinct(x) for x in schemaTrans.columns]
schemaTrans.groupBy("ID").agg(*exprs).show(5)
|  ID|(DISTINCT COL1)|(DISTINCT COL2)|(DISTINCT COL3)|(DISTINCT COL4)|(DISTINCT COL5)|(DISTINCT ID)|
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------|ID01|      2        |      2        |      2        |      3        |      5        |      1      |
|ID02|      2        |      2        |      2        |      4        |      3        |      1      |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------

Comment: But I would like to have:

+----+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+

|  ID|(VL COL1) | (VL COL2) | (VL COL3) | (VL COL4) | (VL COL5) | (VL ID)|
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|ID01|      3   |      3    |      3    |      3    |      2    |     1  |
|ID02|      2   |      2    |      2    |      2    |      2    |     1  |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+

Comment: Please do not add these as comments. [Edit] your question and put it there. Please also read [how do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also check out [how to make good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Answer (score 42):

It's more or less the same:

```
spark_df.groupBy('column_name').count().orderBy('count')
```

In the groupBy you can have multiple columns delimited by a `,`

For example `groupBy('column_1', 'column_2')`

Comment: Hi Tanjin, thank you for your reply! I am not getting the same result. I have been dong the following: (Action-1): from pyspark.sql.functions import count

exprs = {x: "count" for x in df.columns}
df.groupBy("ID").agg(exprs).show(5), this works but I am getting all the record count for each group. That's NOT what I want. (Action-2) from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct

exprs = [countDistinct(x) for x in df.columns]
df.groupBy("ID").agg(*exprs).show(5)  This breaks!! It errors out as follows: ERROR client.TransportResponseHandler:

Comment: The missing `.show()` that you need to add onto the end of that line to actually see the results might be confusing to beginners.

Comment: To match the behavior in Pandas you want to return count by descending order:
`spark_df.groupBy('column_name').count().orderBy(col('count').desc()).show()`

Answer (score 16):

try this when you want to control the order:

```
data.groupBy('col_name').count().orderBy('count', ascending=False).show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
spark_df.groupBy('column_name').count().show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, desc
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('whatever_name').getOrCreate()
spark_sc = spark.read.option('header', True).csv(your_file)    
value_counts=spark_sc.select('Column_Name').groupBy('Column_Name').agg(count('Column_Name').alias('counts')).orderBy(desc('counts'))
value_counts.show()
```

but spark is much slower than pandas value_counts() on a single machine

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupBy('column_name').count().orderBy('count').show()`

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.